# Fragment onCreateView With ConstraintLayout Not Adherring to ConstraintSet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am building all my UI programmatically without the use of XML files. My main UI class inherits from AppCompatActivity() and uses a Fragment called ClientFragment for the main part of the UI

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val layout = ConstraintLayout(this)
    layout.id = R.id.constraint_layout_main_activity
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    setContentView(layout)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.constraint_layout_main_activity, ClientFragment(), "CLIENT_FRAGMENT")
            .commit()
    }
}
```

}

I have an abstract base Fragment class called BaseGridFragment that all my fragments are going to implement. BaseGridFragment contains all the widgets that show up on screen.

```
abstract class BaseGridFragment : Fragment() {
protected lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
protected lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
protected lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter
private lateinit var constraintSet: ConstraintSet
private lateinit var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager
protected lateinit var searchView: SearchView

protected val requestSender = RequestSender()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    context?.let { context ->
        val layout = ConstraintLayout(context)
        layout.id = R.id.constraint_layout_base_fragment
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        progressBar = ProgressBar(context)
        progressBar.id = R.id.progress_bar_all_loading

        searchView = SearchView(context)
        searchView.id = R.id.search_view_base_fragment
        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.isIconifiedByDefault = false

        gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        recyclerAdapter =
            RecyclerAdapter {
                onItemClicked(it)
            }

        recyclerView = RecyclerView(context)
        recyclerView.id = R.id.recycler_view_all_list_of_items
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager

        swipeRefreshLayout = SwipeRefreshLayout(context)
        swipeRefreshLayout.id = R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_all_item_list_container
        swipeRefreshLayout.addView(recyclerView)
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener { fetchData() }

        layout.addView(swipeRefreshLayout)
        layout.addView(progressBar)
        layout.addView(searchView)

        constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.search_view_base_fragment, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
        constraintSet.connect(
            R.id.search_view_base_fragment,
            ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.LEFT
        )
        constraintSet.connect(
            R.id.search_view_base_fragment,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.TOP
        )
        constraintSet.connect(
            R.id.search_view_base_fragment,
            ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.RIGHT
        )
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.search_view_base_fragment, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(
            R.id.search_view_base_fragment,
            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.progress_bar_all_loading, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.progress_bar_all_loading, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
        constraintSet.centerHorizontally(R.id.progress_bar_all_loading, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
        constraintSet.centerVertically(R.id.progress_bar_all_loading, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)

        constraintSet.connect(
            R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_all_item_list_container,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            R.id.search_view_base_fragment,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
        )
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(
            R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_all_item_list_container,
            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        constraintSet.connect(
            R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_all_item_list_container,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
        )

        constraintSet.applyTo(layout)

        searchView.visibility = View.GONE
        swipeRefreshLayout.visibility = View.GONE

        return layout
    }

    return null
}

abstract fun fetchData()

abstract fun onItemClicked(item: RecyclerAdapter.Item)
```

}

ClientFragment implements this abstract class and it is responsible for fetching the data that will populate all the widgets.

```
class ClientFragment : BaseGridFragment() {
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Clients"

    fetchData()
}

override fun fetchData() {
    requestSender.sendRequest(context!!, "/api/clients", JSONArray()) { result ->
        when (result) {
            is RequestSender.RequestSenderResult.Success -> {
                if (result.data.length() != 1) {
                    return@sendRequest
                }

                recyclerAdapter.items.clear()

                val clients = result.data[0] as JSONArray
                for (i in 0 until clients.length()) {
                    val client = clients.get(i) as JSONArray
                    if (client.length() != 3) {
                        Log.e(
                            "ClientActivity",
                            "Invalid client data length while parsing client response. Skipping client."
                        )
                        continue
                    }

                    recyclerAdapter.items.add(
                        RecyclerAdapter.Item(
                            client[0] as String,
                            client[1] as String,
                            URL(client[2] as String)
                        )
                    )
                }

                // Clearing data and calling notifyDataSetChanged() is relatively expensive. If
                // number of items returned causes UI smoothness problem consider notifyDataSetChanged
                // for specific indexes.
                activity!!.runOnUiThread { recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }

                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                swipeRefreshLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                searchView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            }
            is RequestSender.RequestSenderResult.Error -> {
                val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                when (result.error) {
                    is RequestSender.RequestSenderError.NetworkError -> {
                        alert.setTitle("Network Error")
                        alert.setMessage(result.error.description)
                    }
                    is RequestSender.RequestSenderError.ClientError -> {
                        alert.setTitle("Request Error")
                        alert.setMessage(result.error.description)
                    }
                    is RequestSender.RequestSenderError.InternalServerError -> {
                        alert.setTitle("Server Error")
                        alert.setMessage(result.error.description)
                    }
                    is RequestSender.RequestSenderError.UnrecognizedNetworkStatusCode -> {
                        alert.setTitle("Network Error")
                        alert.setMessage(result.error.description)
                    }
                    is RequestSender.RequestSenderError.UnableToDeserializeResponse -> {
                        alert.setTitle("Deserialization Error")
                        alert.setMessage(result.error.description)
                    }
                }
                activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                    alert.create().show()
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    swipeRefreshLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onItemClicked(item: RecyclerAdapter.Item) {
    (activity as MainActivity).onClientClicked(item)
}
```

}

When I run this code the ConstraintSet in the BaseGridFragment is not working correctly. When the app first starts there is a network call to fetch some data. As the data is being fetched I show a spinner in the middle of the screen. After the data is downloaded the UI changes to show a search bar at the top and a CardView below it.

The root View in MainActivity is a ConstraintLayout and so is the main view inside BaseGridFragment which contains all the other widgets. I've color coded the two main views: Green for the layout in MainActivity and Blue for the layout in BaseGridFragment.

[image][image]

Based on my understanding of how supportFragmentManager works the following code should make the layout in BaseGridFragment be a direct child of the layout in MainActivity. Consequently, any constraints I have defined in BaseGridFragment that reference ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID should work:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.constraint_layout_main_activity, ClientFragment(), "CLIENT_FRAGMENT")
            .commit(
```

As you can see from the screenshots the blue areas are not expanding into the green as they should: the spinner is not centered and the CardView does not show up at all under the search bar. If I refactor my code and I get rid of all the fragments and simply put everything that is in my BaseGridFragment layout into my activity then everything works so there must be something about fragments that I'm missing here.

I've searched for a solution to this but all the examples I've come across use XML to define their UI and then use the inflater in onCreateView().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see you set layout params to the main layout

`layout.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)`

Comment: Ya that's what was missing. So I added it to the layout that was inside BaseGridFragment but I didn't have to in the MainActivity. Does the root layout have these layout params by default?

Comment: I am not sure but you can use Tools -> Layout Inspector to see the exact layouts and their params